# docusign embedded with a template

Tags: python, python-3.x, docusignapi

I'm trying to create an embedded signing flow using a template, and I've followed the walk throughs, but for the life of me, I can't seem to get the rest API to work with me after I've created the envelope.  From what I understand, I'm supposed to get a signing URL by requesting a recipient view, but every time I do that, the API complains that my recipients are not set up correctly.  I can't set up recipients in the envelope request because I am using a template.

The flow that we are going for is (1) user begins signup process by entering his or her information on our website, www.mycompany.com; (2) user completes signing on docusign; (3) user is redirected to www.mycompany.com to complete signup process.

The question: **What do I need to do to get a url that I can use to redirect the user to docusign from my web app**

Here's my code:

```
def create_envelope(self, template_id, client_user_id, email, full_name, next_url, **values):
    tabs = Tabs()
    tabs.text_tabs = [
        Text(tab_label=key, value=('%s' % (value,)) if not isinstance(value, str) else value )
        for key, value in values.items()
    ]
    member_role = TemplateRole(
        email=email,
        name=full_name,
        role_name='signer',
        client_user_id=client_user_id,
        tabs=tabs,            
    )
    envelope = EnvelopeDefinition(
        email_subject='%s agreement' % (full_name,),
        template_roles=[ member_role ],
        template_id=template_id,
        status='sent',
    )
    api = EnvelopesApi()        
    summary = api.create_envelope(
        settings.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID,
        envelope_definition=envelope)
    # At this point, everything is fine, and we get a valid envelope
    # but the next call to create a recipient view fails with an HTTP 400        
    envelope_id = summary.envelope_id
    data = RecipientViewRequest(
        authentication_method='email',
        client_user_id=session_key,
        email=email,
        return_url=next_url,
        user_id=settings.DOCUSIGN_USER_ID,
    )
    response = api.create_recipient_view(
        settings.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID,
        envelope_id,
        recipient_view_request=data)
    return response.uri
```

---

Here is the error from the create recipient view:

```
{
    "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
     "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}
```

If I specify as `recipient_id` of `'1'`, I get the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
    "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it turns out that the semantics of `user` changes between the call in creating the envelope to the call when creating the view request.  In the call to create the view request, we have to pass the recipient's full name/user id, and not the api name/user id:

```
data = RecipientViewRequest(
    authentication_method='email',
    client_user_id=session_key,
    email=email,
    return_url=next_url,
    user_name=full_name,
)
```